# Excessive trustd errors in console (no CA revocation file found)

Tags: keychain

I've been experiencing a lot of lag on my system, some of which was addressed with the latest 11.1 update. But looking at my console, I see this error several dozen times a minute:

skipping further reads. no CA revocation additions found: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “CARevocation.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Library/Keychains/CARevocation.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdc06d0f4d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I don't think this is expected behavior, and I'm unsure how to proceed. Any recommendations? Would a reinstall address this?